# select and insert mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to select one column from other table and insert it into another one.

I have column named `image` in table2  and want to select that and insert along with the below data to table1. is that possible?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into table1 (username, firstname, lastname, image) ")
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $fname, $lname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Is there any relation between table1 and table2 ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos there is none.

Comment: Then how do you know what image to insert into table1 from table2? The Guys posted answers before understand the problem. That is awkward :P

Comment: @JorgeCampos No we didn't. We answered the _specific_ question, _and_ addressed the concerns, each his own way. Look again.

Comment: @geomagas Thats ok. I like to think that I'm here to help not to create another questions to the OP. But I get your point.

Comment: @JorgeCampos If you can make _any_ OP **think** by implying "Sure I can give you an answer, but there _are_ things you haven't considered", then you have done something right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
  insert into table1 (username, firstname, lastname, image) 
  select ?,?,?,image from table2
  ");
```

...but I hope table2 has only one row!

Comment: Then maybe `table2` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `INSERT ... SELECT` query - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO table1 (username, firstname, lastname, image)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, image FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.image_id = ?
```

The first 3 `?` are your bound params - `$username, $fname, $lname`
`t2.image_id = ?` represents the id/unique field of your desired img.